# How to match list of urls with a list of patterns (a regex)

Tags: python, regex, list, url

I have a list of urls and I want to find the name of service from given list of url pattern and names, Currently I pick a url and match it with all the patterns, Since both list can be huge, what the best way for url(s) pattern matching and finding the service name?
Current Implementation is below.

urls
http://www.facebook.com
http://0.facebook.com
http://m.facebook.com
http://www.linkedin.com

Pattern        service name
facebook.com   Facebook
linkedin.com   LinkedIn

```
def get_service_name(url, services_details):
    url = url.rsplit('?')
    # urls pattern matching
    for service in services_details:
        if len(url) > 1:
            if service[0] in url[0]:
                return service[1]
        else:
            if service[0] in url:
                return service[1]
    return "Unknown Service"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`urlparse` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html), parse your URLs, and look at the netloc attribute.

Compare it against a dictionary of services that would look like:

```
{
    'facebook.com': 'Facebook',
    'linkedin.com': 'LinkedIn', 
}
```

You might need an extra normalization step to remove or add a leading `www`.